# Why the tags of my tumblr theme look like bright blue links?

Tags: tumblr

I have a [blog on tumblr](http://kirawonrey.tumblr.com), and the tags show up like bright blue links that are really difficult to read and it looks awful.

I'm not going to change the theme, because I love it. At first this theme didn't show the tags, so I read some things around the internet and found some code that made the theme show the tags. I know very little html, but messing around I figured out how to modify the tags and make them look like I wanted. The thing is they look like they should on the Customize menu but when someone looks at my blog they don't look the same way.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aV7bf.png) is how I want them to look and how it looks on the customize menu.

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b5E1.png) is how the tags look when you go to my blog. (As you can see, I'm losing my mind)

I don't understand why it is different, or what's the problem. I don't understand anything anymore.

What can I do?

Comment: This seems to be solved. If you can just post what you did as an answer that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to hit the blue `Save` button after `Update Preview` button when customizing the theme.